# ID Card PHP Data superimposing Card background image

Tags: php, html, css, overlay

I have the following scenario. A card reader that reads an ID card and gets the data and displays them in a table (webpage). What I am doing now is removing the table, inserting the ID Card image in the background and superimposing the card data on the image in the appropriate position, i.e. the user photo on the card's photo position, the user's name on the card's Name position etc.
When I try to put the card image in the background either directly as table/form background image, or through css, most of the time it doesn't show right or does not show at all. when it shows, I can not get the data to superimpose correctly. I have tried through css, divs with z-index etc, and nothing works correctly. I can see the data but can not arrange them on the ID card image. Here's the code I have been working on. This is a php webpage we are talking about.

```
<div id="login" class="login">

<form id="iform" name="iform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>">

<table class="tabcont" width="100%" valign="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="main area">

<tr><td align="center" class="listlr" colspan="2">

</td></tr>

<tr><td align="center" class="listlr" colspan="2">

</td></tr>


<?php if (is_array($result) && count($result) > 0): 

foreach ($result as $reskey => $resvalue) {

if ($reskey == 'Surname')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";

if ($reskey == 'FirstName')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";   

if ($reskey == 'DateOfBirth')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";   

if ($reskey == 'PlaceOfBirth')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";

if ($reskey == 'NationalID')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";

if ($reskey == 'Sex')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";

if ($reskey == 'Nationality')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";

if ($reskey == 'DocumentNumber')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";

if ($reskey == 'CardEffectiveDate')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";

if ($reskey == 'CardExpirationDate')
echo "<input class='formfld' value='{$resvalue}'/>";

echo "<tr><td width='0%'></td>";
echo "<td width='0%'>";                                       

if ($reskey == 'CardholderPortraitImage')
echo "<img id='{$reskey}' src='{$resvalue}' value=''/>";                          

if ($reskey == 'CardholderHandwrittenSignatureImage')
echo "<img id='{$reskey}' src='{$resvalue}' value=''/>";

echo "</td></tr>";

}

else: ?>                   

<tr> <td>
<?php
echo "<div align=\"center\" class=\"listtopic\" id=\"iderror\">{$errormsg}</div>";
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>

</table>
</form>
</div>
```

I am also trying to wrap php in DIVs like so to get to arrange the data files through css and z-index, but nothing happens:

```
echo '<div class="image">';

echo '</div>';

<div class="foto">';

<?php if ($reskey == 'CardholderPortraitImage')

echo "<img id='{$reskey}' src='{$resvalue}' value=''/>";                                                 
?>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create an image programmatically...it will be easier, and will look the same in all browsers.

Comment: The main problem is not the image, it's the data overlaying the image. They don't show right and they don't respond to css formatting.

Comment: I meant, programmatically make a new image with the data overlaid on the old image, using like imagemagick or some other image library in php.